# Is there a library behind Spring roo's text-based interface?

Tags: command-line, spring-roo

I would like to create my own text based interface.

Did spring roo create their [text based interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/usage.html#usage-shell) from scratch or did they use a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey JavaRocky, Roo uses [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at [roo.shell](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/org.springframework.roo.shell/apidocs/index.html?index-all.html) and particularly, the CommandMarker and @CliCommand and how to use these two.

Following may be of interest -

- [Roo documentation - Chapter 15.
  Simple Add-Ons](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/simple-addons.html)
- [Writing Add Ons for Spring Roo
  Framework – 1- Hello World](http://rishikhare.wordpress.com/2009/11/10/writing-add-ons-for-spring-roo-framework-1-hello-world/)
- [Spring-Roo internals and add-ons](http://www.slideshare.net/desmax74/spring-roo-internals-javaday-iv)